# Applying If[] to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

So I have a list of values

```
truthValues = {True, True, False}
```

and for each element of the list, I would like to return a different value if that element is true or not. So I would like to return this array if everything is true:

```
trueList = {1, 1, 1}
```

And this array if everything is false:

```
falseList = {0, 0, 0}
```

So for the list of values above, I would like to return

```
{1, 1, 0}
```

But the If[] function doesn't appear to support this directly, and the Apply function doesn't seem to do the trick either. Ideas?

Comment: Or if you need other return values than `0`/`1`, you could try `truthValues /. {True -> something, False -> somethingElse}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simplest to use `Map` like this:

```
If[#, 1, 0] & /@ {True, True, False}
```

> {1, 1, 0}

or `Boole` is straightforward as it's designed for such purposes:

```
Boole @ {True, True, False}
```

> {1, 1, 0}

`Boole` will return `0/1`, but if you want something different to work with later, use `If`.

Comment: For your 1st two code segments, I'm having them evaluate to {True, True, False}. The map works perfectly, though.

Comment: Indeed; I must've mixed some outputs while copying, sorry for that. I edited not to make confusion. Nevertheless, `Map` is the usual way when you want to use `If`.

Answer (score 4):

```
MapThread[ If , {{True, True, False}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

> {1,2,6}

or per comment:

```
Thread@If[{True, True, False}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]
```

> {1,2,6}

with a caveat the `Thread` form only works if you use an explicit list argument.
For example you can't do this:

```
falselist = {4, 5, 6};
Thread@If[{True, True, False}, {1, 2, 3}, falselist]
```

> {1, 2, {4, 5, 6}}

resulting from `If`'s `HoldRest` attribute. ( you could do `Thread@If[{True, True, False}, {1, 2, 3}, Evaluate@falselist]` )

Comment: And again you came up with a better version than mine. Also the first time i've seen MapThread being really usefull. Again: thanks ^^

Comment: Even Thread should work here

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, yes.. added to the answer.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, because `If`'s `HoldRest` attribute can break the intended behavior: `Thread[If[truthValues, trueList, falseList]]` evaluates only `truthValues` at first and ends up giving a list of 3 results (in OPs example `{trueList, trueList, falseList}`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming everything can be in your false and true list:

```
truthValues={True,True,False}
trueList={a,b,c}
falseList={x,y,z}
```

- the straightforward way is to use [Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to "iterate" over your lists
  `Table[If[truthValues[[i]],trueList[[i]],falseList[[i]]],{i,1,Length[truthValues]}]`

  > {a,b,z}
- a better way is to use [Apply](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (which even matches your question "applying [...]"):
  `If[#1,#2,#3]&@@@Transpose[{truthValues,trueList,falseList}]`

  > {a,b,z}

Comment: even just do `If @@@ Transpose..` for the last case.